# Recurring Flow to Set Compliance

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate

I have an 'Apparatus List'.

I am currently using number of columns and calculations in calculated columns to update compliance status of annual pump test.

Each piece of apparatus has a unique license number ('LicNo' - Text).

There is a Status ('Status' - Text) column and 'LastPmpTst' column ('LastPmpTst' - Text).

Each piece of apparatus needs to be pump tested every 365 days. I'd like to create a Recurring flow on the SharePoint list (once every 24 hours).
[image]

Comment: Hi Curtis. Are you using SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server?

Comment: The site is SP Online.

Answer (score 0):

In flow, we could use **Recurrence** trigger condition to run flows on a schedule
and use **Update item** action to achieve your requirement.

References:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers

Comment: Yes, I understand. What would the flow look like? What component would I need to make it work?

1. Trigger
2. SP Update Item

Is that all? Will I need anything else to complete the flow?

Comment: Yes, if you want detailed steps, please provide more information about your list, such as screenshot and your specific requirement.